# Is the word "field player" a synonym for "outfield player" in the context of association football? Does it even exist?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I'm currently working on a user interface which has the option to filter a list of football players based on their general position, so to either show all goalkeepers or all players playing on the other positions. There is a term for the latter, "outfield players", but I've also read and heard the word "field player" a lot and assumed it was a perfectly fine synonym. Also, in German, my native language, the word "Feldspieler" is a valid word and actually the only option I know of.

But it seems like "field player" is not really as widely accepted/used as I thought it was. For example, the [Wikipedia article for "Association football"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football) only uses "outfield player" and the [Cambridge Dictionary only has "outfield player"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outfield-player), [searching for "field player" returns no results](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=field%20player). Even just googling the term was a weird experience, like I just invented it. It seems like "field player" **is** widely used within the term "field player gloves" by multiple manufacturers though, to distinguish them from goalkeeper gloves.

While I don't really care if "field player" is in a dictionary or if Wikipedia editors feel like it is a word, I do care about if people understand the term as a synonym for "outfield player" and if it will "feel" alright, especially for native speakers.

Basically, if you had two buttons and a list of footballers below in front of you, would the button texts "goalkeepers" and "field players" make sense to you (and most people) or not?

EDIT:
[The Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=field%20players%2Coutfield%20players%2Cfield%20player%2Coutfield%20player&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfield%20players%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutfield%20players%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfield%20player%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutfield%20player%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfield%20players%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutfield%20players%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfield%20player%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutfield%20player%3B%2Cc0) also shows that "outfield player" is more popular, but it seems that wasn't the case just 15 years ago:
[image: Google Ngram of "outfield player"]

The plurals show a similar trend:
[image]

I'm really unsure why.

Comment: You may be getting some false hits because, although we'd normally just call them "outfielders", there are players in the "outfield" in baseball.

Comment: *I do care about if people understand the term as a synonym for "outfield player" and if it will "feel" alright, especially for native speakers.* This native BrE speaker and long-time football fan has never encountered the term *field player* to mean everyone in the team apart from the idler between the sticks.

Comment: What @ThePhoton said. Before drawing conclusions make sure you have ruled out all occurrences of “outfielder” related to baseball.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Huh. I mean I gotta believe you and the dictionary I guess, thanks! But just for example, here a search of "field player" in /r/soccer: https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/search/?q=field%20player&restrict_sr=1

The club badge flairs seem to suggest most of the people using the term aren't native speakers though. But I also haven't found any commenters confused about the word. Looks like this is a misused english loan word similar to some of those Indian English ones. Interesting.

Comment: As I read the Wikipedia article and related links, I’d conclude *midfielder* is the common term. Other positions, besides goalkeeper, are forward and defender. There are various terms (as in American football) reflecting playing strategies.